# Android image part onclick

Tags: java, android, image, layout, onclick

I have a big image as this one  [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Counties_of_Hungary_2006.png/450px-Counties_of_Hungary_2006.png)

Can I have that in Android if somebody click on "Pest" just Pest changes its Background color ?
My goal is to have a separate onClickListener for all county and they can change their background.

Can I achieve it in Android?
Thank You !

Comment: Yes, yes you can achieve this in Android.

Comment: How ? Can you give me some info ?

Comment: Use Android Studio

Comment: Probably separate ImageViews or something similar. Beyond that, I would suggest googling and see what you come up with, make an attempt, and return here with a more specific question.

Comment: I use it. But these is a big image. So If I set an onClickListener to this image thwhole image's background will be changes. I would just that county where the user clicked.

Comment: Okey, I will try it !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this seems more like a graphics design issue.

Secondly, it is definitely doable. I would suggest some form of Photoshop to split the bigger image in sub-images. Once you have your 10 images (random number, but I suppose you get the ieda) that together form the bigger image (that should 100% be achievable with a Photoshop like software), then you can apply the `onClickListener` to each image. This will produce the effect you are looking for.

I believe you know how to do that and you might not need the code (as I have seen in your comments). All you need is that Photoshop like software that will do all the work for you.

Meanwhile, I will quickly search about the best software to crop those images. If you have Photoshop that might prove quite good, I guess.

Maybe this (there are tons out there):

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/i-need-to-slice-one-image-into-50-different-images-automatically